# Converting equations to polar form

Tags: calculus

Convert the following rectangular equations to polar form:

\begin{align}\text{(i)  } y&=−x,\; y≥0 \\\text{(ii)  } 0&=x^2+6x+y^2−4y+12\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you know anything about converting between cartesian and polar coordinates that might be helpful here?

Comment: Please try to use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Converting the first equation should be immediate if you know how $x$ and $y$ are transformed. For the second equation, completing the squares is a good place to start.

Comment: Show us what you've been working on; otherwise, people will not answer lest you were just interested in getting some homework out of the way (even if it is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you know that $x= r \cos(\theta)$ and $y= r \sin(\theta)$.

$y= -x$ so $r \sin(\theta)= r \cos(\theta)$ which reduces to $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}= \tan(\theta)= 1$  That is true for $\theta= \frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\theta= \frac{3\pi}{4}$.  The condition that y> 0 means that $r \sin(\theta)> 0$.  Since r is never negative, $\sin(\theta)> 0$ which means $0< \theta< \pi$ so $\theta= \frac{\pi}{4}$.

$x^2+ 6x+ y^2- 4y= 12= 0$ becomes $r^2 \cos^2(\theta)+ 6r \cos(\theta)+ r^2 \sin^2(\theta)- 4r \sin(\theta)+ 12= r^2+ 6r \cos(\theta)- 4r \sin(\theta)+ 12= 0$.